# Does US federal law prohibit the possession of an uncontrolled prescription drug without a prescription, and if so, according to which provision?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, medical, us-federal-government

What specific provision in US federal law, if any, prohibits the possession of an uncontrolled prescription drug without a prescription? I've had a lot of trouble finding the answer to this question, since most of the information available relates to controlled substances. I assume this would be found in the Federal Food, Drug, and Cosmetic Act, but have not been able to find it within the U.S. Code section (I haven't read the entire text, but have tried searching extensively). I am completely sure that I am asking about a substance not listed in any schedule of the Controlled Substances Act, e.g. [propranolol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propranolol).

I am also aware that there are provisions about importing these, but I am not asking about that. I am asking about the situation once such a drug is simply found in the possession of someone without a valid prescription for it, with no record of how they obtained it.

Comment: A lot of this is done at the state level vs the Federal level. If you can give an example of the state that this is of concern in, we can narrow this down. Generally for Federal laws, this would fall under [21 USC Title 21 Chapter 13](https://www.deadiversion.usdoj.gov/21cfr/21usc/). For example in Alaska anything that doesn't fall into it's schedules is considered Schedule VIA. Unless you are facing a Federal charge, it's the state laws you should be concerned about...

Comment: @RonBeyer: 21 USC Chapter 13 is very long, and from its title would appear to deal exclusively with *controlled* substances, which is not what this question asks about.  If you're aware of a specific provision in that chapter that's relevant to this question, can you give a more specific reference?

Comment: Anon: Do you have some particular reason to think such a law exists (e.g. something you have read)?  If you can give more background, it might help someone track down an answer.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, but from [this page](https://www.deadiversion.usdoj.gov/schedules/): *These are not comprehensive lists so please note that a substance need not be listed as a controlled substance to be treated as a scheduled substance for criminal prosecution.* So the regulations/punishments would apply, even if it doesn't appear on a "controlled substance list". Mostly though as I said, this isn't a Federal thing, possession of a prescription that is not in your name is almost entirely state law so I don't think 21 USC Ch13 really applies.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thanks for your comments! In reply to your first comment: I am only interested in federal laws for this, so if it turned out that it was only regulated at the state level, then the answer to the question would be "there are none." It seemed to me more likely that the answer would be found in the Act I mentioned (USC Title 21 Chapter 9).

Comment: @NateEldredge re your first comment: yes, exactly, I am not asking about controlled substances. And Ron re your second comment, I don't think that statement about lists not being comprehensive is relevant since the context seems to be in regard to things like analogs, isomers, etc. of controlled substances. Here I am limiting the scope to substances that are not scheduled and have no relationship to anything that would be scheduled (I'd be surprised if propranolol were scheduled anywhere).

Comment: I think that statement was referring to the possibility that carfentanyl could be treated as scheduled in a prosecution if fentanyl is scheduled even if carfentanyl isn't explicitly, or things within that vein.

Comment: @NateEldredge re your second comment (and Ron re your first comment again): I'm not sure; perhaps not. Otherwise, it would also be interesting to see if anyone has already catalogued which states do and don't have the kind of law Ron mentioned applies in Alaska (interesting find!). I just checked MA and NY somewhat randomly, and it seems that MA has an identical law to the one in Alaska (any federally unscheduled Rx drug is automatically controlled as Schedule VI), but NY doesn't seem to have such a law (but I didn't check exhaustively; it's obviously easier to confirm than to infirm).

Comment: Almost by definition, the fact that something is a "prescription drug" implies that it is subject to legal regulation under federal or state law, with a penalty for violating it, even if the controlled substances act of a particular jurisdiction in its main criminal code isn't the statute imposing the limitation.